# problem to execute overlay analysis for multiple layer in python script

Tags: arcpy, error-999999

I wrote the code to get a series of weighted overly result for multiple layer in python script. But it showed some error massage. What can be the solution?

```
import arcpy
input1 = "D:\work\helath.gdb\Reclass_Heal1"
a = arcpy.da.SearchCursor (input1, 'Value')
input2 = "D:\work\helath.gdb\Reclass_Heal2"
b = arcpy.da.SearchCursor (input2, 'Value')
input3 = "D:\work\edu.gdb\Reclass_Educ1"
c = arcpy.da.SearchCursor (input3, 'Value')
input4 = "D:\work\edu.gdb\Reclass_Educ2"
e = arcpy.da.SearchCursor (input4, 'Value')
output = r"C:\Users\d\Documents\ArcGIS\Default1.gdb"
input5 = [input1, input2]
input6 = [input2, input4]
value1 = [a, b]
value2 = [c, e]
for i in range(0,len(input5)):
        for j in range(0,len(input6)):
                for k in value1:
                        for l in value2:                      
                                weighted = output + "\\didar_"+ str(k)
                                arcpy.gp.WeightedOverlay_sa("('input5[i]' 50 'value1'(value[k] 1;value[k] 2;value[k] 3; value[k] 4; value[k] 5; value[k] 6; value[k] 7; value[k] 8; value[k] 9;NODATA NODATA); 'input6[j]' 50 'value2' (value[l] 1; value[l] 2; value[l] 3; value[l] 4; value[l] 5; value[l] 6; value[l] 7; value[l] 8; value[l] 9; NODATA NODATA);1 9 1", weighted)
```

The error massage is:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 20, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
>   504, in      return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
>   ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Failed to
>   execute (WeightedOverlay).

What is the meaning of ERROR 999999 and how this can be solved?

Comment: `k` is a cursor object, you can't convert it to a string.